# Cleaning the signal from noise

Tags: time-series, noise, structural-change

I have a following signal, and I want to correct the part which has a sharp jump, based on the value of the signal sometimes before the jump and its future values.

Instead of that jump I want something like a red line or green line, or something in between (sth that is most likely to be the signal instead of that noise based on the behavior of the signal in the pas and in the future.)
Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Please explain what a "correction" would be.  It sounds like you have in mind some idealized behavior to which your data do not conform, but exactly how do they depart from it?  (In many contexts the circled points would be considered an important part of the "signal.")

Comment: Does the procedure need to identify the jump as well as smooth it over, or will you identify the jump?

Comment: I have already found the maximum of the jump which in this case is the dot which is at lfp=8000  But I don't know how far I should go left and right and remove those "noise" and put some other values instead.

Comment: It night help to have an idea of what you want to do with the "corrected" signal. The entire character of the signal seems to perhaps change after the jump (e.g. acquiring a strong periodic component).

Comment: I want to find the power of the signal in the range of 6-12 Hz.

Comment: Why don't you share your data ?

Comment: Band stop filter will attenuate if you know the frequency. Looks like first instance of some component.